# EasyPHP: setting working directory simply fails

Tags: easyphp

If one image worths more than 1000 words lets simply show the issue

https://youtu.be/1-1s-SkuENE

I have set up the working dir as follow
[image]

Restarted the server

But when I try to visit the page (http://127.0.0.1/edsa-superinformati_tmp or http://127.0.0.1/superinformati_tmp)

It gives me an error.

This should be the basic of easy PHP how can it be broken?

Comment: I've never had this problem. Can you give us more information. Try to remove and redo your alias. Does it work if you put your folder somewhere else (not in `eds-www` nor `Program files(x86)`)

Comment: @PeterEstiven: I'm sorry the real problem was with the https.. anyway I think many dev would consider EasyPHP a more "mature" product if it would show an hint of what is the problem..

Comment: You won't  find any product that will tell you that you type the wrong address. Especially if you mix http and https. How could the product know ? Apache said that the connection was refused. It cannot do more.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, and didn't find any answer, here or elsewhere.

But I finally managed to understand what was the problem: it comes from EasyPHP adding its new prefix `edsa-` to whatever directory name you cite when defining an alias.

If you want to work with, say `test`, it's saved as `edsa-test`.
From this, when you try accessing to:

- `127.0.0.1/test`, EasyPHP doesn't recognize it as a registered alias
- `127.0.0.1/edsa-test`, it recognizes it but tries to reach the 
  `edsa-test` directory, that obviously doesn't exist

I found that registered alias are saved as a PHP serialized array in `YourInstallFolder/EasyPHP-Devserver-17/eds-dashboard/store_alias.php`, which looks like:

```
a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:10:"alias_path";s:12:"/path/to/test";s:10:"alias_name";s:9:"edsa-test";}}
```

You have to modify this file to change the alias name, like this:

```
a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:10:"alias_path";s:12:"/path/to/test";s:10:"alias_name";s:5:"test";}}
```

In this example `s:9:"edsa-test"` becomes `s:5:"test"`, because you must:

- drop the `edsa-` prefix
- AND
- adjust the cited string size behind it (always 5 less than original size)

Here the beginning `a:1` means that only 1 alias was registered; it may be `a:N`, where N is the number of registered aliases.
Repeat this for each of them.